# How to connect mousedown and mouseup events for selector and document

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

So i'm trying do this:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.selector', function(){
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(){
       // some actions
    });
});
```

which is fire some action after `mouseup()` event on document after `mousedown()` event on specify selector, is it posible? Can anybody help?

Comment: do you want to bind the mouseup event once the user makes a mousedown trigger?

Comment: yeah, but on specify selector

Comment: i dont get the question? what is not working? why not set the selector like you did in the first line?! make jsfiddle

Comment: i don't wanna do this on the same selector but on the whole document body...

Comment: so whats wrong with `$(document).on('mouseup', function(){`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$(".selector").mousedown(function(){
         $(".selector").mouseup(function(){

         })
    });
```